# Contact of Nodes with Subclass

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

im creating a class to add my Meteors to the scene:

```
import SpriteKit

class Meteor: SKShapeNode {

    var meteorNode : SKShapeNode?
    var size : CGSize!
    //Acoes
    var acaoApagar = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    var acaoAndar : SKAction!

    //Numero Randomico
    var numRandom : Int = 0
    var textoStringMeteor : String!

    //Colisoes
    let CollisionShoot     : UInt32 = 0x1 << 0
    let CollisionHouse : UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
    let CollisionMeteor : UInt32 = 0x1 << 2

    init(size : CGSize, pontoMeteor: CGPoint, textoMeteor: String)
    {
        super.init()
        //super.init(ellipseOfSize: <#CGSize#>)

        self.size = size

        self.textoStringMeteor = textoMeteor
        self.acaoAndar = SKAction.moveTo(pontoMeteor, duration: 10)

        criarMeteoro()
        setarTexto(self.textoStringMeteor)

    }

    func setarTexto(numeroLabel : String) {

        let numNode = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"Chalkduster")
        numNode.text = numeroLabel;
        numNode.fontSize = 20;
        numNode.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -10);
        numNode.name = "textoNode"
        meteorNode?.addChild(numNode)

    }

    func criarMeteoro() {

        var randomX = CGFloat(Int(arc4random()) % Int(size.width))

        //Meteor Node
        meteorNode = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: CGFloat(20))
        meteorNode!.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 20)
        meteorNode!.physicsBody!.dynamic = true
        meteorNode!.fillColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        meteorNode!.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = CollisionMeteor
        meteorNode!.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = CollisionShoot | CollisionHouse
        meteorNode!.position = CGPoint(x: randomX, y: size.height + 900)
        meteorNode!.name = "meteorNode"
        self.addChild(meteorNode!)

        meteorNode!.runAction(SKAction.sequence([acaoAndar, acaoApagar]))    
    }


    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


}
```

Here im calling the class Meteor and passing all parameters:

```
 var meteor = Meteor(size: CGSize(width: size.width, height: size.height), pontoMeteor: ponto, textoMeteor: "30")

    foreground.addChild(meteor)
```

And for the last i have my contact to see if there was contact between the nodes:

```
 func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

        var bodyA = contact.bodyA!.node!
        var bodyB = contact.bodyB!.node!

        if bodyA.name == "tiroCanhao" && bodyB.name == "meteorNode"
        {
            bodyB.removeAllActions()
            bodyB.removeFromParent()
            bodyA.removeFromParent()
            self.pointsPlayer++
            self.qtdtiros += 2



        }
        else if bodyA.name == "meteorNode" && bodyB.name == "tiroCanhao"
        {
            bodyA.removeAllActions()
            bodyA.removeFromParent()
            bodyB.removeFromParent()
            self.pointsPlayer++
            self.qtdtiros += 2

        }
}
```

Now my problem is the follow:

After the contact i want to call the setarTexto method on the Meteor class of the object and change the text but that isnt working. I get this error:

> Could not cast value of type 'SKShapeNode' (0x10bb5ea88) to
>   'MathDefense.Meteor' (0x10af6b7b0).

What im doing is this (on the if statement on contact):

```
let text = bodyB as! Meteor
text.setarTexto("20")
```

I even tried

```
text.textoStringMeteor = "20"
```

But none of those worked. I already done some research but didn't find any person with my problem or trying to do something similar.

Any solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, to fix my error i made the following:

Remove the SKShapenode since the class is already a SKShapenode (that was the error).

Then when creating my node i made everthing with self instead of putting in the Meteornode. That fixed all.

Example:

Right: self.position = CGPoint(x: randomX, y: size.height + 900)

Wrong: meteorNode!.position = CGPoint(x: randomX, y: size.height + 900)

To pass texture if you are using a SKSpritenode just put it on your superinit.